# PHP Capture the results from an array into a variable - the variable must contain both the match and the corresponding line from the array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a file containing a list of IP addresses i.e.:

```
1.1.1.1
2.2.2.2
3.3.3.3
```

I use the PHP "geoip_country_code_by_name" to match an IP in the list to a country code and if a country code matches then I echo out the country code.

This works but what I want to do is also echo out the matching IP in the file i.e. GB 1.1.1.1 and also save the results into a variable i.e. $match

Overview of what code I have:

```
<?php

$ipfilename = "iplist.txt";
$contents = file($ipfilename);

foreach($contents as $line) {
  $country = geoip_country_code_by_name($line);
  if ($country == "GB") {
   echo $country;
   } 
}
?>
```

Hopefully this makes sense, happy to try and clarify more if required.

I have tried looking at the PHP [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) but i cant work it out.

I have also tried this:

```
<?php

$ipfilename = "iplist.txt";
$contents = file($ipfilename);

foreach($contents as $ip => $line) {
  $country = geoip_country_code_by_name($line);
  if ($country == "GB") {
   echo $country;
   echo print_r($ip);
   } 
}
?>
```

But this echo's out the country code and the array number/key i.e GB01

** **EDIT** **

Some progress!

I can now get the matching country code and IP to echo out with this code:

```
<?php

$ipfilename = "iplist.txt";
$contents = file($ipfilename);

foreach($contents as $ip => $line) {
  $country = geoip_country_code_by_name($line);
  if ($country == "GB") {
   echo $country;
   echo " ";
   echo $line;
  }
}
?>
```

This gives me GB 1.1.1.1

For the last part how do i save those echo results as a variable?  $match

Comment: "GB01" would be executing 2 lines the first being GB the second being Other country according to https://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/codes. you may need to add a line break character at each echo line ."/n"

Comment: Thankyou @happymacarts I have managed to get the counrty code and IP now using the code in my edit, just got to get it into a variable now.

Comment: You are calling `geoip_country_code_by_name()` on every line of your file, every time you open the file?  This feels pretty heavy handed.  Shouldn't you cache the country code in the file as well?

Comment: @mickmackusa I would if I knew how   currently this is working as per the answer but always happy to improve it if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally did it:

```
<?php

$ipfilename = "iplist.txt";
$contents = file($ipfilename);

foreach($contents as $ip => $line) {
  $country = geoip_country_code_by_name($line);
  if ($country == "GB") {
   $match .= "$country $line \n";       
  }
}
echo "<br><br> $match <br><br>"; 
?>
```

When you echo $match it gives you:

**GB 1.1.1.1**

Answer (score 0):

Your application requires both the country code and (I assume) one or more ip addresses that belong to that country.

For this reason, it will be far more efficient in the long run to structure your data storage as a json file with the first level keys being the country code and all ip addresses existing in subarrays.

When you need to access the ip addresses from a specific country, your "reading" process will be very quick.

```
$match = 'GB';
$ipArray = json_decode(file_get_contents('ip_lists_by_country.json'))->$match ?? [];
```

From this point, you can `var_export($ipArray)` to see the zero-or-many ip addresses that belong to that country.  Or if you want to loop and present the array of ip addresses, that *could* look like this:

```
foreach ($ipArray as $ip) {
    echo "<div>$match: $ip</div>";
}
```

---

Creating and maintaining the json file takes a little more effort, but still not much.

1. Call `geoip_country_code_by_name()` using the supplied ip address to generate the country string.
2. Open the json file and decode the file as an object (you could make is an array if you prefer to work with arrays).
3. Check if the country does not exist in the lookup file OR if the specific ip address is not found within the specified country.
4. If the new ip address should be stored in the file, push the new element into the targeted subarray, `json_encode()`, and then overwrite the original json file with the new version of itself.  Done.

I recommend this:

```
$filename = 'ip_lists_by_country.json';
$newIP = '7.7.7.7';
$country = geoip_country_code_by_name($newIP);
$object = json_decode(file_get_contents($filename));
if (!isset($object->$country) || !in_array($newIP, $object->$country)) {
    $object->$country[] = $newIp;
    file_put_contents(json_encode($filename, $object));
}
```

---

Okay, since the ip file is a resource maintained outside of your application and is a very short list of ip addresses, then I'll just offer an alternative filtering syntax to gather the zero or more qualifying ip addresses.

```
$country = 'GB';
$ipsInCountry = array_filter(
    file('iplist.txt'),
    function($ip) use ($country) {
        return $country === geoip_country_code_by_name($ip);
    }
);
var_export($ipsInCountry);
```

Comment: unfortunately I cannot edit the contents or format of the file containing the IP addresses as it comes from a 3rd party and changes often, but thank you for the time to give an answer.

Comment: Can you tell me how many ip addresses are typically found in this file? Is it relatively large or relatively small?

Comment: Its very small, it can be anywhere from 1 IP Address to 16.

Comment: Ah, okay, then my advice is a classic case of premature optimization / over-engineering.

Comment: No worries :) thanks for the effort its much appreciated.